# How to get Firefox fully working on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: firefox

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new PC. Been using the Firefox snap that comes shipped with it for a couple of days, but after the scrolling was not very smooth and also the pinch zoom feature was not working, I decided to switch to the apt version following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/823631). Now I got a better scrolling and pinch zoom but when I play music on YouTube it does not "connect" to Gnome and so I don't have control of the playback from my bluetooth headphones (play/pause/skip song, etc). I don't know if there are other features missing yet.

Is it possible to install one Firefox version that just works as expected?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm using the Firefox snap on much older --and likely lower-spec-- hardware. Scrolling is smooth. Gnome connectivity works properly. Bluetooth connectivity works properly. Your pick of the culprit may perhaps be premature, and more troubleshooting might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the better experience by keeping the snap version of Firefox and starting Ubuntu with Xorg instead of Wayland (whatever that means) by changing the selection in the login screen:

[image]

Now the scrolling is much more precise and I got back the inertial/kinetic scroll, as well as the Gnome desktop connectivity to control playback. The two finger pinch to zoom still does not work on the touchpad.

Answer (score -1):

After you removed Firefox and reinstalled it As [the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401) you sent show

You need to install Codecs on Ubuntu for Firefox to fix running videos and music problems that you are facing

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse

sudo apt update

sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

After that enable DRM:

Menu Bar -> Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Digital Rights Management (DRM) Content -> Play DRM-controlled content

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem relevant to the problems at hand.

Comment: I saw that he didn't install codecs after he reinstalled Firefox, I think that maybe fix the problem.

Comment: Did not solve the issue.

Comment: Well, sure, the OP have not mentioned installing codecs, because they are irrelevant. The lack of codecs would manifest in a player not being able to handle proprietary formats, but that is not the problem. How are codecs supposed to help with scrolling, pinch to zoom and bluetooth connectivity? :~)

Comment: The post said that he already fixed zoom and scrolling by reinstall that on the link above @mikewhatever

Comment: Right, so codecs and DRM are not for scrolling and zoom. What are they for?

Comment: @mikewhatever His problem now with playing music on Youtube, you can know all that if you read his post well.

Comment: @user171780 I don't think the problem with Firefox, if it's running well with every option, you have to find if the problem with the Bluetooth device

Comment: I just gave priority to the music control playback over inertial scrolling and pinch zoom, so I simply went back to the snap version. I don't think the problem is from the bluetooth device because with the snap version I can control the playback from gnome's notification window and with the apt version this cannot be done either.